# USB + Ruida connection tty0

Tags: usb

I've been connecting to an Atomstack CNC laser in Ubuntu 20.04 and the software Lightburn for some time and it works perfectly. I recently bought a new machine with Ruida controller, but can't get get Lightburn to find it although Lightburn with Win10 works with the same machine.

I've done the following,

dmesg | grep tty
[    0.157327] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[  835.768647] usb 8-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0

and my user belongs to dialout and tty groups.

Lightburn using GRBL on tty0 was able to connect to the Atomstack, but doesn't find the Ruida controller.

Can anyone give me a hint on where to look, what to try next?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I just noticed that lightburn has an error message, "A network error occurred: Error creating SSL context ()

Comment: 2 things 1. put the info about the error in the question with EDIT not as a comment. 2. Did you check and see if that device works with Ubuntu? I would be checking the makers site if that was me and see what they have to say about it.